# android dialog problem

Tags: android, error-handling, dialog, android-alertdialog, customdialog

When using a custom dialog in an Android App how is it then possible to let the user know, that he/she has entered a wrong argument, e.g. a wrong password or username?

Possible an AlertDialog or just a Toast_Message?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a textview to your customdialog, if the user/password combination fails, you only need to display this textview with the message wanted.

It will be better than AlertDialog, 2 consecutives dialog aren't good for the user. And the toast message are not always understandable for all users.

Comment: Yes. That is also my last solution, if nothing else is possible. Just wondered if it was possible to give a short error message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you want in principle. Flash the screen and all LEDs generate all possible sounds to make the phone R2D2s clone on speed.

On a more serious note. A `Toast` notification can be used but is not necessarily a good option since it could happen that the users just does not pay attentions and misses the whole notification resulting in a confused user as he is expecting the application to log him in.

Now there is the `AlertDialog` notification which is probably the most suitable notification type to inform a user about something critical he did or didn't. It requires users attention which is exactly what you want in such cases.

There would be the `StatusBarNotification` which is meant to display an ongoing process. Best example would be a download or something.

Another option would be an appearing `TextView` which needs to be distinctive enough to be easily noticed by the user and of course the layout has to be planned to support such dynamic changes.

My recommendation is the `AlertDialog` and if not applicable for some reason then the dynamic `TextView`.

Comment: I would like a AlertDialog to popup, when I have a CustomDialog open (Without closing the CustomDialog). If that is possible? How about using the EditText to let the user know that there is a problem?